# Change title of webform

Tags: views, theming

I added a webform to my site. Everything works fine, except that the title (surrounded red) is saying "webform", but I want it to change to "Kontakt" (as the title in the form itself).

[image]

Theme is "TB Corpal".

Two questions:

1. What is the right terminology for this type of title? Is this just called "title" or what is the proper name in drupal?
2. How can I change that? (I already tried the module "Automatic Nodetitles" but this changes just the title in the form istself)

Or can I do this using "views"? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer here:
http://www.themebrain.com/question/how-change-string-title-bar

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the theme you are using is doing this. The answer may have nothing to do with the Webform module.
When you use a Theme provided by a company that sells themes, you are building your site ontop of a site that they already built for you. Yes, this saves some time, but sadly, you have to find out how that site works. Often times, they have made some "very interesting" decisions that can not be easily explained.

Do you have a link to this page? I am wondering if maybe that title is appearing in a BLOCK. If you mouse over that title, does a gear appear to the far right of that title?

As for the terminology, I do not know. This does not sound like the way Drupal handles titles. I suspect the crew that built this theme made interesting decisions.
The webform module simple creates nodes where the content is fields.
Each webform-node has a node-title in the same way that all nodes have titles.
To edit the title of a node, simply edit the node and change the title and save it. The new title should appear.
If this is not how your site works, then whoever built the theme is doing something very strange.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your answers :)